# Send receive data wireless 6 kms C code

Tags: wifi

i want to send data over wireless medium in the range of 6 kms.
what is the best method to achieve this. Is this Wi-Fi or some other method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking line of sight, WiFi would be possible, with the kit needed costing around 300 euro or up. That is of course largely dependant on your requirements like throughput, influence of bad weather, budget...

Comment: can you share the link of that kit which you are referring here

Comment: Radiolabs has an affordable one: http://www.radiolabs.com/products/wireless/point-to-point-bridge.php